# Streaming logs in API 37 and up

Tags: logging, streaming-api

In API 36 you could subscribe to a streaming topic (`/systemTopic/Logging`) for logs.  As of API 37, that no longer seems to work.

How do you subscribe to the logging steaming topic in API 37+?

Comment: An interesting observation. Looking at the Developer Console in Spring 17, it is still using the `/cometd/36.0` (Spring '16). Maybe something to do with the Platform Events (Beta).

Comment: I can confirm that using v37.0 onward doesn't work with that systemTopic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Confirmation from twitter that they are making changes around supporting platform events in the future. [Twitter Exchange](https://twitter.com/_johnbrock/status/845094682447282176):

> **Me**
> Why would the #Salesforce Developer Console still be using v36 of cometD for systemTopics?
>
> **John Brock**
> #SafeHarbor internal teams are working on support for system topics for v37+ and yes, it's related to plat event beta

Comment: Quoted relevant content here so it's more permanent/accessible. Hope that's okay!

Comment: Thanks @AdrianLarson. I posted the answer via my mobile and was going to circle back to expand on it. Looks like you beat me to it :)